# Parse Server Cloud Function Queries Not Prepending Mount Path

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-server, mlab

Following the recent announcement that Parse is discontinuing their service, I've recently began moving my data and server. I've got my data migrated to mLab, and have setup my server on heroku.

My issue: **queries from my app (iOS swift) work fine, but queries from my cloud code don't.**

Here is what the logs from heroku look like:

```
at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/Recipe" status=200
at=info method=POST path="/classes/Ingredient" status=404
at=error method=POST path="/parse/functions/getIngredients" status=503 desc="Request timeout"
```

What I've done above:

1. fetched data from 'Recipe' with swift via PFQuery
2. called the cloud function 'getIngredients' with swift via PFCloud

My cloud function 'getIngredients' attempts to fetch some data from 'Ingredient' via Parse.Query. From what I can see, the problem is because '/parse' is not being prepended to the query made from within the cloud code.

I'm using Express and Node.js (following the instructions [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App)). In initializing the ParseServer instance: 'appId', 'masterKey', 'serverURL', 'databaseURI', and 'cloud' are all set.

- My mountPath is set to '/parse'.
- My serverURL has '/parse' appended to the end.
- And in my AppDelegate, I am also appending '/parse' to the Parse.server configuration.

I've tried every permutation of removing and adding '/parse' to those 3 locations, and get the same (or more erroneous) results each time. Queries from within swift work, but not from within the cloud functions.

Has anyone else had this problem?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539331/cloud-code-functions-are-not-executing-with-parse-server-open-source-api) question is related, but doesn't address my specific problem.

Comment: could you help with some snippets of your code?